# Insert jsonObject into apache ignite using queries

Tags: ignite

How to insert JSONOBject into apache ignite using sql queries? I have defined a column with varchar and tried to insert as below 
`INSERT INTO Car (id,name) VALUES (1,'{"device_id": 123456789012,"time": "2018-04-30T14:07:18.402Z","speed": 0}')`

This shows error..
Moreover i want to pass the JsonObject rather than string..
How to achieve this???

Comment: Please show the error in question!

Answer (score 0):

Apache Ignite has no specific support for JSON in SQL, meaning that you should use VARCHAR and String values as displayed.

Why it won't work for you is not obvious without the error message.

Comment: error is with the double quotes used is insert query for 'name' column . I know i have to use backlashes, which i dont want to... How else can it be achieved??? Is it impossible??

Comment: @Pooja you can use JDBC variable binding to `?`, but the statement that you have provided should work also. I have tried it and it works for me.

Comment: `con.execute("INSERT INTO Emp (id,name) VALUES (1,'{"device_id": 123456789012}')", insertOutput -> {
      if (insertOutput.succeeded()) {
      `

Comment: I tried just now, still shows error saying `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable`

Comment: @Pooja you should be fixing your Java code here, it is unrelated to Apache Ignite.

Comment: Thank u, but i'm unable to fix it.. Will find some other way.. Thank u so much for good explaination. Can i query a Cache<String,JsonObject> using SQL statments??

Comment: I know that Cache<String,Person>, can be queried using SQL. But how about the above???